# Strange behavior when formatting string to number for Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

The behavior of `str1` and `str2` that is different.
I expected that `str2` is `15.4`.
Why?

```swift
let str1 = String(format: "%.1f", Double("12.55")!) // 12.6
let str2 = String(format: "%.1f", Double("15.35")!) // 15.3
```

- Xcode 12.0
- Swift 5.3

Comment: Print `String(format: "%.20f", 15.35)` and you'll see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hitting an issue having to do with [how numbers are stored in a computer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). But you are basically writing C code, which is not a good thing to do in Swift. For better consistency in rounding behavior, use a NumberFormatter:

```
let f = NumberFormatter()
f.maximumFractionDigits = 1
let str1 = f.string(from: 12.55)!
let str2 = f.string(from: 15.35)!
print(str1, str2) // 12.6 15.4
```

Comment: I actually wonder why NumberFormatter behaves differently. The closest representable binary floating number to 15.35 is *less* than 15.35 (its about 15.34999999999999964), so the correct rounding to one fractional digit should be 15.3.